# Error is sending simple form to database using php

Tags: php, mysql, database

Want to create a simple form to send the values and image to database, below is the php code -

Created two php file process_upload and connection

processs_upload.php

```
<?php

require 'connection.php';
$conn    = Connect();

$name=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$mobile_number=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['mobile_number']);
$email_id=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['email_id']);
$type=$conn->real_escape_string($_POST['type']);

$query   = "INSERT into tb_cform (name,mobile_number,email_id,type) VALUES('" . $name . "','" . $mobile_number . "','" . $email_id . "','" . $type . "')";

if ( 0 < $_FILES['image_file']['error'] ) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $_FILES['image_file']['error'] . '<br>';
}
else{
    $time=time();
     if(($type=='image/png') || ($type=='image/gif') || ($type=='image/jpeg') || ($type=='image/pjpeg') || ($type=='image/jpg')){ //if file is image

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], 'pictures/'.$time.'_'.$_FILES['image_file']['name'])){
    echo 'done ';
 }else{
    echo 'image error';

 }    


 }else{//if file is video

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'], 'videos/'.$time.'_'.$_FILES['image_file']['name'])){
    echo 'done';
 }else{
    echo 'video error';

 } 

 } 


 }
$conn->close();
?>
```

connection.php

```
<?php


function Connect()
{
 $dbhost = "localhost";
 $dbuser = "user";
 $dbpass = "";
 $dbname = "database";

 // Create connection
 $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die($conn->connect_error);

 return $conn;
}

?>
```

Created a table in phpmyadmin and below is the table -

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_cform` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `mobile_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email_id` text NOT NULL,
  `type` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

HTML form

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<meta name="author" content="Boomer" />

<title>Uploader</title>
<link href="css/upload_css.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function(){
 var optionsH = { 
        target:   '#H_output',   // target element(s) to be updated with server response 
        beforeSubmit:  beforeSubmitH,  // pre-submit callback 
        uploadProgress: OnProgressH,
        error:   onerrorH,
        success: afterSuccessH,  // post-submit callback 
        resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
        }; 



        $('#MyUploadFormH').submit(function(){ 

        var name=$("#name").val();
        var mobile_number=$("#mobile_number").val();
        var email_id=$("#email_id").val();
        if((name!='') && (mobile_number!='') && (email_id!='')){
         $('#MyUploadFormH').attr("action","process_upload.php");
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(optionsH);           
        // return false to prevent standard browser submit and page navigation 
        return false;  
        }else{
        $("#H_output").html("All field are required");    
        }

        });

        function beforeSubmitH(){
        //check whether browser fully supports all File API
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob)
        {

        if(!$('#imageInputH').val()) //check eHty input filed
        {

        $("#H_output").html("select picture or video to upload");
        return false
        }else{
        $("#H_output").html("file selected"); 
        }

        var fsize = $('#imageInputH')[0].files[0].size; //get file size
        var ftype = $('#imageInputH')[0].files[0].type; // get file type

        switch(ftype)
        {
        case 'image/png': case 'image/gif': case 'image/jpeg': case 'image/pjpeg': case 'video/mp4': case 'video/3gp': case 'video/avi': case 'video/mkv': 
        case 'video/flv': case 'video/wmv': case 'video/ovb': case 'video/ogg': 
        break;
        default:
        $("#H_output").html("<b>"+ftype+"</b> Unsupported file type!");
        return false
        }


        //Allowed file size is less than 1 MB (1048576)
        if(fsize>10485760) 
        {
            $("#H_output").html("<b>"+bytesToSize(fsize) +"</b> is too big! <br />Please reduce the size and try again."); 
            return false
        }




        document.getElementById("header_submit-btn").setAttribute("disabled", true);        
        $("#H_output").html("");  
        }
        else
        {
        //Output error to older unsupported browsers that doesn't support HTML5 File API
        $("#H_output").html("Please upgrade your phone!");
        return false;
        }
        }

        function OnProgressH(){
        $("#upload_formH").hide();
        $("#upload_loader_header").show();
        }
        //when error occur
        function onerrorH(){
        document.getElementById("header_submit-btn").removeAttribute("disabled", true);
        $("#H_output").html("connection error...");
        //$('#staff_bfr_uplad_prv_cnt').html("");
        //progressboxH.hide();
        //$('#MyUploadForm').resetForm();
        $("#upload_formH").show();
        $("#upload_loader_header").hide();
        }




        //after succesful upload
        function afterSuccessH()
        {
        document.getElementById("header_submit-btn").removeAttribute("disabled", true);
        $("#upload_formH").show();
        $("#upload_loader_header").hide(); 
        var logo_thumb=$("#header_pix_location").html(); 
        $("img[id^='eml_header_logo']").attr('src',dp_thumb);

        }



    document.querySelector('#H_fileSelect').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var fileInput = document.querySelector('#imageInputH');
    //clickH(fileInput); // Simulate the click with a custom event.
    fileInput.click(); // Or, use the native click() of the file input.
    $("#H_output").html(""); 
    }, false);



    $("#imageInputH").change(function(){

    var fsize = $('#imageInputH')[0].files[0].size; //get file size
    var ftype = $('#imageInputH')[0].files[0].type; // get file type
    if(fsize>10485760){
    $("#H_output").html("<b>"+bytesToSize(fsize) +"</b> is too big! <br />Please reduce the size and try again.");    
    document.getElementById("header_submit-btn").setAttribute("disabled", true); 
    }else{
     $("#type").val(ftype);   
     $("#H_output").html("<span style='color: green;'>file selected</span>"); 
     document.getElementById("header_submit-btn").removeAttribute("disabled", true);   
    }

    });



    //function to format bites bit.ly/19yoIPO
function bytesToSize(bytes) {
   var sizes = ['Bytes', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB'];
   if (bytes == 0) return '0 Bytes';
   var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
   return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
}

});




</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="add_cpp_form">
    <center>
    <div style="float: none; width: 270px; padding: 10px;" id="upload_formH">
    <form onSubmit="return false" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="MyUploadFormH">
<input type="text" class="form_input" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Name" />
<input type="text" class="form_input" id="mobile_number" name="mobile_number" value=""  placeholder="Mobile Number" />
<input type="text" class="form_input" id="email_id" name="email_id" value="" placeholder="Email Id" />

<input name="image_file" id="imageInputH" type="file" />
<input name="type" id="type" type="hidden" />
<input type="submit"  id="header_submit-btn" class="effect1 ripple" value="Submit" />
<div id="H_fileSelect" class="effect1 ripple" style="border-radius: 0px;">Select</div>
<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" id="loading-img" style="display:none;" alt="Please Wait"/>
</form>
<div id="H_output"></div>
</div>

<div id="upload_loader_header"  style="float: left; display: none; text-   align: center; width: 100%;">
<img style="float: none;" src="img/ajax-loader.gif" width="32" height="32" />
</div>
</center>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Now when i am running the code I am getting image error and video error message, the connection is successfully done but getting the message.

Comment: verify the destination forlder exists and has permissions. if(!is_writable($directory)){//not writeable  }

Comment: make sure form enctype="multipart/form-data" is set. check with var_dump($_FILES) in processs_upload.php

Comment: @PhpDev and Parth Shah - Please explain in detail as new in php and database

Answer (score 0):

Try grant permissions as in

suppose your code are under /var/www/my_project

try chmod -R 664  /var/www/my_project.

Comment: I have changed the permission to 664 but now I am getting connection error, previous permission was 755

Comment: I checked again and process_upload.php and connection.php both have 664 permission so i guess it is not a permission issue

Comment: post your html form